# mapView on top of TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I made a simple app using Swift. I one viewController with a MapView and a tableView. The tableView is displaying the data and the mapView is showing the locations correctly. But the problem is when i scroll the tableView, the mapView does not move up, it stays in place. I want the mapView to scroll up with the tableView. Is there any way of doing this using storyboard ? Or do i have to make it programatically ?

I found some objective-c sample code on github which show how to make the mapView scroll with the tableView. But unfortunately I don't know much objective-C and could not understand the code.

I am using UIViewController, MapView and TableView

Comment: Are you using a UIViewController or a UITableViewController?

Comment: If you want it to be part of the table view, you can add it as a tableHeaderView -- they scroll with the table. But to do that, you need to add your map view to the table not the controller's main view.

Comment: i get this error: "mapViewOutlet" cannot have a prototype object as its destination.

Comment: It sounds like you tried to add it to the cell rather then the table view. It's easier to get it right by adding it to the object list on the left side of the canvas instead of trying it on the canvas.

Comment: thanks a lot :')
I have been trying to fix this for more than a week.